# The method window.top.postMessage Redirected to initial page

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

Hi I have two page in the iframe(index.html,another-one.html).
index.html has a button which redirected to another-one.html
 once another-one.html sent message using window.top.postMessage causing it redirect back to initial one.

1. index.html (page loaded initially)
2. another-page.html.
3. Trigger window.top.postMessage from another-page.html
4. Redirected to initial page.

Expected should stay at index.html

Host Page or Container Page loaded with index.html

host page code

```
  <iframe src ="http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html" name="example" id="example" application="yes">
    </iframe>
```

js code in host page

```
window.addEventListener("message", (e)=>{
  if(e && e.data){
    this.pagedata  = e.data;
  }
}, false);
```

code of index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TEST1</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(()=>{
        $("#redirectButton").click(()=>{
            window.location.href="./another-page.html";
        });
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body >
    <button id="redirectButton" type="button">Redirect</button>
</body>
</html>
```

code of another-page.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>New Page</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(()=>{
        $("#btnMessage").click(()=>{
            let obj = {
                message:"this is new message"+(new Date())
            };
            window.top.postMessage(obj, '*');
        });
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body >
    Another Page
    <input id="btnMessage" type="button" value="Send Again"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't see how `window.top.postMessage` would trigger anything at all, much less a page load - seeing as there's absolutely no code that handles a `message` event

Comment: $("#btnMessage").click(()=>{
            let obj = {
                message:"this is new message"+(new Date())
            };
            window.top.postMessage(obj, '*');
        });

Comment: Yes, that's the code that dispatches the event - You'll see that I said **there's absolutely no code that *handles* a `message` event** - so, can't see how a postMessage would cause anything at all to actually happen anywhere